# Is the in_array function a safe way of blocking code injection/sql injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection, code-injection

If i have a php  file which is receiving a $_GET['value'] is it safe from sql injection or code-injection for me to start my php file with

```
if (in_array($_GET['value'], $allowed_values);) 
{ /* normal page code handling the $_GET['value'] */ 

 } else { unset($_GET['name'])
 }
```

$allowed values is obviously an array of all values which i am expecting as safe for $_Get['value']. Is this still unsafe? Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the values in `$allowed_values` and the actual code you have, but yes. When you can limit the input that way and the possible values cannot be used for code injection/sql injection, then it is save.

Comment: Yes, but not explicitly. This is a form of validating your input and is something you should always do, but it technically doesn't do anything to prevent SQL injection at a technical level. For example, if one of your allows values was actually `' or 1=1--` it would still get injected, compared to using parameters to actually disallow SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's discuss this thing in little details:

Your code is like this :

```
if (in_array($_GET['value'], $allowed_values);) { 
 ...........
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = $_GET['value']";
 ...........

} 
else { 
  unset($_GET['name'])
}
```

now let's assume, you have some values :

the **in_array()** function will allow only some pre-defined values, you couldn't have the option to take custom user input by $_GET, but as only pre-defined values are allowed,any SQL command will be safe inside if statement.

now take this example of $allowed_values array :

```
$allowed_values = ['some details' , 'another details' ,3, ' 105; DROP TABLE mytable;', 22 , 'ok'];
```

If any of these array values have a string that can have potential SQL injection capability, then there will be an issue. but I think you will not put any such string in the array $allowed_values. ( in this above-mentioned example, index 3, ' 105; DROP TABLE mytable;' can delete the table mytable ). else the SQL command will be safe.

now you can add an extra layer of safety in the code, by using PDO for any SQL query. (in this example you do  not need that, as **in_array()** function is 100% safe unless you yourself put any malicious code in the array, as per my above-mentioned example). but for other types of user input where you have to do some SQL query depend on the user input, you can use PDO -prepared statement.

a PDO example is this :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (username, kname) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([  $username , $kname   ]);
```

For more info, try w3school link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thank you Mr Pahari for me it was it was truly a tie between yours and Mr Karwin's answer his was so concise yet covered allot of ground  and yours was more detailed in some areas. Each has its merits. Impossible to choose.

Comment: to be concise: in_array() is the safest thing, but you only take pre-defined inputs. if anything is not under the "$allowed_values" array, the if statement will not pass.  but if you want to take user input where you d  not know what the put will be: use REGEX and PDO-Prepare stamement to safeguard  sql injection.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's a common and safe technique that can be used in situations where query parameters can't be used. For instance, if the value will be used as a table or column name, you can't provide it as a query parameter, you have to substitute it directly into the SQL string. Whitelisting like this is the recommended way to ensure that this is safe.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the values in the `$allowed_values` array, and how you are interpolating the value into your SQL query.

For example:

```
$allowed_values = [ 'a word' ];

if (in_array($_GET['value'], $allowed_values)) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = {$_GET['value']};";
}
```

Definitely not safe. It results in the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = a word;
```

This is a syntax error.

Why would you not just use SQL query parameters? Then you don't need to worry if it's safe or not. Query parameters separate the values from the SQL parsing, so there's no way any kind of value can cause SQL injection.

You won't have to have an `$allowed_values` array. You won't have to remember to check if the GET input is in the array. You won't have to worry about quoting or escaping.

It's true that query parameters only work for values, that is in place of a quoted string literal or quoted datetime literal or numeric literal. If you need other parts of your query to be dynamic, like the table name or column name or SQL keywords, etc. then use an allow-list solution like you are showing.

But the more common case of interpolating dynamic values is better handled by query parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt-execute( [ $_GET['value'] ] );
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Clearly put forward and concise. Thank you.